# Service account to access UNC

Tags: security, webdav, bdc

I'm trying to access the UNC to copy a file from the UNC share to another location. The way it is set up it requires an interactive challenge for credentials, and I was told there is no way to change that setup. I was told that if we set up a Secure System Store that we could somehow impersonate a user and have our SSIS package be able to copy the file from the UNC drop location without manual intervention.

However, I can't find out what to do next. I've read up on BDC but it doesn't seem to apply to the situation - but more to the database. Can someone point me to some documentation that might help me?

Answer (score 0):

The SSIS package can interface with SharePoint's webservices and has the capability to run as an identity that can be supplied to the system/content source and execute the copy.  You can also do this with a schedule powershell script or console app and supply the credentials.

Comment: When I try to run with SSIS I get failures because of the forced challenge I'm hitting. I don't know how to connect the SSIS package to the SSS ID. Just trying to pass credentials isn't working.